# How to install the "sound" library for Processing in a simple way?

Tags: audio, processing

It's just so weird that Processing does't come with a "sound" library while the official information provides related information(https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/).  This only leads me to the Github source code page(https://github.com/processing/processing-sound) and I literally do not know how to install this thing...

Yes, I could use the "Minim" or "Sonia" library. But I have a bunch of example programs which use the "sound" library, each with a "import processing.sound.*;" right at the beginning.

In addition, I can't find anything named "Sound" in the Processing library manager..

What's going on with this library? How do I install it easily?

---

update

---

I'm asking this because there is actually no option to install it:
[image]

Even when I search:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From your Processing PDE, go to the **Sketch** menu, then expand the **Import Library** submenu, and select the **Add Library...** option.

[image: Processing libraries menu]

That will open up a dialog that lists libraries you can install, including the Sound library.

[image: Processing libraries dialog]

Install it, and you'll be able to use the classes in the `processing.sound` package.

Comment: Perhaps it is because of the Mac version doesn't come with it. But it's still very strange..

Answer (score 2):

You may download the .jar file of the library you need and put it in a folder named "code" in your sketch folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Mac you can still add the library but it's a bit more complicated. You need to download the library and open the finder/documents/processing/libraries and drop the sound folder that you download from the web in the the libraries folder. You then open Processing and add the library through the library manager.

Comment: Actually it's not that simple. I think I have to install MethCla to take advantage of the shared library.