# Using Processing Sound Library in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, processing

I'm not sure how to import the Sound Library for processing into my IntelliJ. I have processing downloaded and have already imported in the core.jar, but when I do import processing.sound.*; it doesn't recognize it, I looked for the Sound file but I don't know where in the processing-3.5.3-windows64 file where the Sound Library is located. I want to use the Sound Library in IntelliJ, please help.

Comment: The `core.jar` file provides the core Processing library. To access the Sound library, you need to include its `.jar` files in your classpath.

Comment: Ok I'm pretty new to all this so sorry if I sound dumb but where do I find its .jar files as you previously stated.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Ok I'm pretty new to all this so sorry if I sound dumb but where do I find its .jar files as you previously stated.

Comment: Generally they'll be in the folder for the library. Check your Processing directory?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Ok, sorry but I'm still a little confused, I'll walk you through everything. I click File then Project Structure, I go down to Libraries, I click the plus, I go down to the folder processing-3.5.3-windows64. In that there are 5 more folders, core, java, lib, modes, and tools. Where do I go from here.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure. I would guess `lib`? You're going to have to poke around until you find it.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Ok, my last question would be what do you use to code with processing?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies.

Comment: @J.Coder Personally I just use the Processing editor. I've also used Eclipse, but you're going to have the same issue in any IDE. You need to track down the `.jar` file for the library.

Answer (score 0):

**Instructions for IntelliJ:**

1. If you still haven't, download Processing from [here](https://processing.org/download/).
2. Unzip the file, navigate to `YOUR-PATH-HERE...\processing-3.5.3\core\library` and find `core.jar`
3. In IntelliJ, create a new Project.
4. Navigate to `File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> Press on + in top left corner -> Navigate to core.jar file`. Import it. It will now become visible under your External Libraries tab on the left.
5. Create a new class, call it Main (can be any name). Fill it with some boilerplate code:

   > import processing.core.PApplet;
   >
   > public class Main extends PApplet{
   >
   > ```
   > public static void main(String[] args) {
   >     PApplet.main("Main");
   > }
   >
   > public void settings(){
   > }
   >
   > public void setup(){
   > }
   >
   > public void draw(){
   > } }
   > ```
6. Now the bad news - there is no ready-to-use jar for Sound in the Processing download, so you will need to compile the jar yourself. Navigate to [processing-sound Github Repository](https://github.com/processing/processing-sound). Follow the instructions in the "How to Build" section. You will end up with a zip file with a `sound.jar` file located inside.
7. Add the jar file to your IntelliJ project, as described above for core.jar.

---

The easiest way to work with Sound in Processing is using the Processing editor that comes with the Processing download.

**Instructions for Processing Editor:**

Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559754/how-to-install-the-sound-library-for-processing-in-a-simple-way) for excellent detailed instructions.

P.S. Working in IntelliJ might be easier with the **Minim library**, might be worth for you to check it out as well.